# An integration in PDE

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations

$$\dfrac{y}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\dfrac{{\rm d}\xi}{(1+\xi^2)\left[(\xi-x)^2+y^2\right]}$$

I am stuck here. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Partial fraction or contour integral will do.

Comment: @Hans Thanks. Yes, I tried, but... failed :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outline of the solution:

Suppose $x$ and $y$ are real numbers and $(x,y)\ne(0,1)$ and denote the integral by $I$. Take the upper hemispherical contour in the complex plane. The part at infinity vanishes. WLOG $y>0$. Let the integrand be $f(z)$.
\begin{align}\frac{\pi}{y}2\pi iI &= \sum\text{Res}[f(\text{poles above the real axis})] \\
&= \frac{1}{2i((i-x)^2+y^2)}+\frac1{(1+(x+iy)^2)(2iy)}.
\end{align}

Comment: Can an elementary method solve this problem？

Comment: @Math: Yes, like I said in the comment above, use the partial fraction.

Comment: Could you be so kind enough as to be more explicit? Detail would be very much appreciated : )

Comment: @Math: Set $\frac{a_1\xi+a_2}{1+\xi^2}+\frac{a_3\xi+a_4}{(\xi-x)^2+y^2}=\dfrac1{(1+\xi^2)\left[(\xi-x)^2+y^2\right]}$ and solve for $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)$. Then integrate.

Comment: yes it is possible with partial fraction decomposition and variable substitution. it will be like logs and maybe some arctan (which is actually a complex log in disguise).